# Pass variable to component view to be used as filter

Tags: angularjs

I've build a simple component that allows passing a filter as a parameter, and I'm trying to use that parameter in the component view, but I don't know how. It gets passed as a string so it's treated as a string in the component view and thus not working.

Basically it looks something like this:

`<number-compare value="some.value" filter="currency"/>`

And in the component view:

`<span> {{ numCompCtrl.value | numCompCtrl.value.filter }} </span>`

But that doesn't work because it gets interpreted as `{{ 10 | "currency" }}`

I've tried to handle it in the controller instead, and apply the filter there but it gets really messy when the filter needs multiple parameters so the easiest thing by far would be if I could get the simple way working.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just discovered that I had already solved this previously with another filter as a workaround

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('core')
    .filter('dynamic', dynamic);

  dynamic.$inject = ['$interpolate'];

  function dynamic($interpolate) {
    return function(value, name) {
      if (!name) {
        return value;
      }

      var result = $interpolate('{{ value | ' + name + ' }}');
      return result({ value: value });
    };
  }
})();
```

And used like this:

`{{ numCompCtrl.value | dynamic: numCompCtrl.value.filter }}`